# java jpanel how to optimise painting

Tags: java, swing, optimization, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am trying to implement langton's ant , and i did it well :
[langton's ant java simulation screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxoMr.png)

for painting in my jPanel, i override the paintComponent at each step but it take so much time for painting every black or white rectangle , i just want that at each step i only paint the two rectangle who have changed!? 
So my question is, how to only paint a rectangle without changing what was painted in previous frame?

here is my code for painting

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        int careLargeur = getWidth() / m;
        int careHauteur = getHeight() / n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
                if(map[i][j]) 
                    g.fillRect(j*careLargeur,i*careHauteur,careLargeur,careHauteur);
            }
        //draw fourmi
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(jF*careLargeur, iF*careHauteur, careLargeur, careHauteur);
    }
```

any help? or should i give more details ? 
here is the jar :

Answer (score 1):

Paint your rectangles to a BufferedImage, and then draw that BufferedImage within your paintComponent method. You could also limit how much is re-drawn by using one of the `repaint(...)` overrides that specifies the exact rectangular region to repaint.

So your paintComponent method could be as simple as this:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (img != null) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(jF*careLargeur, iF*careHauteur, careLargeur, careHauteur);
}
```

With drawing changes being made to the `img` BufferedImage.

Assuming that you're using a Swing Timer to drive the state changes to your model, you could

1. change the model, and then
2. update the BufferedImage based on the model changes, and
3. call `repaint(...)` on only the updated region.

Incomplete code attempt.... not yet done!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

/**
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/44930371/522444
 * @author Pete
 *
 */
public class LangtonsAnt {

    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 30;

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Model model = new Model(800);
        View view = new View(800);
        Controller controller = new Controller(model, view);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Langtons Ant");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(view);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        controller.startTimer(TIMER_DELAY);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static class Model {
        public static final String POINT = "point";
        private SwingPropertyChangeSupport support = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
        private int gridSize;
        private boolean[][] grid; // false is white. Better to use enums
        private Point oldValue;
        private Point point; // ant location

        public Model(int gridSize) {
            this.gridSize = gridSize;
            grid = new boolean[gridSize][gridSize];
            int x = gridSize / 2;
            int y = gridSize / 2;
            setPoint(new Point(x, y));
        }

        public void setPoint(Point point) {
            this.oldValue = this.point;
            Point newValue = point;
            this.point = point;
            support.firePropertyChange(POINT, oldValue, newValue);
        }

        public Point getPoint() {
            return point;
        }

        public boolean[][] getGrid() {
            return grid;
        }

        public int getGridSize() {
            return gridSize;
        }

        public void step() {
            // first will hold relative new positions
            int newX = 0;
            int newY = 0;
            boolean gridPoint = getGridPoint(point);
            if (oldValue == null) {
                newX = point.x;
                newY = point.y - 1;
            } else {
                int dX = point.x - oldValue.x;
                int dY = point.y - oldValue.y;
                if (dX != 0) {
                    // from left or right
                    newY = dX > 0 ? 1 : -1;  // assume "white" or false
                    newY = gridPoint ? -newY : newY;  // if "black" then reverse
                } else {
                    // from up or down
                    newX = dY > 0 ? -1 : 1; // assume "white" or false
                    newX = gridPoint ? -newX : newX; // if "black" then reverse
                }

                // convert from relative to absolute new positions
                newX = point.x + newX;
                newY = point.y + newY;
            }
            setGridPoint(point, !gridPoint);
            setPoint(new Point(newX, newY));            
        }

        public boolean getGridPoint(int x, int y) {
            return grid[x][y];
        }

        public boolean getGridPoint(Point p) {
            return getGridPoint(p.x, p.y);
        }

        public void setGridPoint(int x, int y, boolean b) {
            grid[x][y] = b;
        }

        public void setGridPoint(Point p, boolean b) {
            setGridPoint(p.x, p.y, b);
        }

        public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener l) {
            support.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, l);
        }
    }

    private static class Controller {

        private Model model;
        private View view;
        private Timer timer;

        public Controller(Model model, View view) {
            this.model = model;
            this.view = view;
            view.setAntImg(createAntImg()); 
            model.addPropertyChangeListener(Model.POINT, new ModelListener());
        }

        private BufferedImage createAntImg() {
            // trivial image for now
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
            g.dispose();
            return img;
        }

        public void startTimer(int delay) {
            timer = new Timer(delay, new TimerListener());
        }

        private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.step();
            }
        }

        private class ModelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                // TODO Finish this.
                // get the new point and old point
                // translate model coord to view coord
                // Change the state of the view's buffered image
                // repaint the limited region that was changed

            }
        }

    }

    private static class View extends JPanel {
        private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.WHITE;
        private BufferedImage gridImg;
        private BufferedImage antImg;
        private Point guiAntLocation;
        private int pixelWidth;

        public View(int pixelWidth) {
            this.pixelWidth = pixelWidth;
            gridImg = new BufferedImage(pixelWidth, pixelWidth, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2 = gridImg.createGraphics();
            g2.setColor(BACKGROUND);
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, pixelWidth, pixelWidth);
            g2.dispose();
        }

        public int getPixelWidth() {
            return pixelWidth;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (getGridImg() != null) {
                g.drawImage(getGridImg(), 0, 0, this);
            }
            if (guiAntLocation != null && antImg != null) {
                int x = guiAntLocation.x;
                int y = guiAntLocation.y;
                g.drawImage(antImg, x, y, this);
            }
        }

        public void setGuiAntLocation(Point guiAntLocation) {
            this.guiAntLocation = guiAntLocation;
        }

        public Point getGuiAntLocation() {
            return guiAntLocation;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (isPreferredSizeSet() || getGridImg() == null) {
                return super.getPreferredSize();
            }
            return new Dimension(getGridImg().getWidth(), getGridImg().getHeight());
        }

        public BufferedImage getGridImg() {
            return gridImg;
        }

        public void setGridImg(BufferedImage gridImg) {
            this.gridImg = gridImg;
        }

        public void setAntImg(BufferedImage antImg) {
            this.antImg = antImg;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and where should i put the drawing of all the matrix? (some time whene we resize the jFrame the jPanel need to be redraw every rectangle no? i want have any problem here)
and i can't draw rectangle instead of image?

Comment: ok thanks, am going to try to change my code, but the only way to draw it's to override paintComponent?

Comment: @NazimeLakehal: that's the best way to draw this.